# Old linked .net 2 dll uses ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings to read values from Web.config file

Tags: .net, dll

I created a new .net 6 project (it's my first project, I'm not an expert) that import a DLL of an old .net2 application. From my code I call a function of a class inside the DLL. The function invokes **ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings** to read a property from Web.config file (I know that because I also have the source code of the DLL and I see the target property inside the Web.config file).

The error that is raised is : **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

How can I solve?

Additional question: when I import a DLL, are the config files associated to the original project, that the DLL in the code is using to read properties, packed together with the DLL? If not (as I presume) how it's possibile to work with that DLL?

I tried to debug the DLL without success.